# Any suggestion for imputing missing values in the following case?

Tags: missing-data, data-imputation

I am doing a 0-1 classification problem. 
One of the features has a really high missing ratio(over 95%). So usually I will drop it.
But for the rest 5%, almost all corresponding dependent variable is 1! So I think it is a good predictor.
So what should I do? Drop it or do imputation?

Comment: will that variable be available at predict time?

Comment: @GuilhermeMarthe I am not sure about that

Comment: @Tian you should confirm this. If the the variable won't be available a prediction time, its quite moot.

Answer (score 0):

What about: missing = 0, and non-missing = 1 ?

Comment: Is there any other possible method?

Comment: A similar method is to create a dummy value for "missing". But, what is wrong with the method suggested in this answer?